# Which NAV2 controller for following a given path with a certain speed?

Tags: ros2, control, nav2

I need to follow a given global path with a certain speed. For now, my plan would have been to use the MPPI controller in NAV2 with a custom critic for speed.

Is this a good approach? Are there other simpler solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty good approach. RPP is also a constant speed controller that sets the linear velocity as constant and computes the appropriate angular velocity to track the path. The "Regulated" in that approach's name includes some heuristics to adjust that velocity, but you can disable them all if you want to charge forward at full speed all the time, all other constraints be damned. It might overshoot some turns by the nature of RPP like that if your robot isn't highly dynamic and while driving fast, where as DWB/MPPI might be better.

Something like MPPI/DWB where you can remove other constraints and highly weight that also seem like logical choices, assuming you wanted to also have other controls than just max speed.